# How to update Json file

Tags: php, android, json, webserver, updates

Thank You all for assistance and attention. I have an Application that reads data from a .json file, all of my files are located on a remote server. What I need to do is update the .json file every time a new file is added to the folder.

Can this be done and if so how? Below is the code I have put together so far to read the contents in the folder and out put .json

```
if($dh = opendir($dir)){
while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
    if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
    } else {
        $return_array[] = $file; // Add the file to the array
    }
}
```

**then I echo the findings**

```
}echo json_encode($return_array);
```

**and below is the .json file I need to update**

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "http://allhiphoprandbandurbanmusicnetwork.com/ahrum_chat/uploads/Jun%205,%202014%206:53:15%20PMkasirisx@gmail.comfreestyle.mp4",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    }

    }
]
```

I am a beginner with Php and .Json so any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As said by vik already it is unclear what your php code has to do with your json array. Please explain better what you want.

Comment: Ok ... when user submits a file i need the file location and type added to the above json file.

Comment: That is stil unclear. I see no json file. Only a json array. Your php code is generating json output but very different from what you show. So why do you think that your php code has anything to do with the shown json array?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the code you provided and how is it related to the .json file, but the basic method of doing this is:

1. Read your .json file into an array(Array1)
2. Read and add all new files into a new array (array 2)
3. Merge Array2 and Array1.
4. Write merged array to the .json file, overwriting everything.

Edited:
Here is an example to make you understand, in the simplest way I can put it:

```
/* users.json
{
    data:[
             {
                 first_name:"Lionel",
                 last_name:"Messi"
             }
         ]
}
*/

// Read your .json file into an array

$fileName = "users.json";
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
$arrayA = $array["data"];

// Read and add new files into a new array

...
...
$arrayB = array(array("first_name" => "Cristiano", "last_name" => "Ronaldo"));

// Merge both arrays

$arrayC = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB);

// Write to .json file again

file_put_contents($fileName, json_encode(array("data" => $arrayC)));
```

Comment: How do I do all of that?